# Как задать стили элемента по клику мыши в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animation

Используется React

```
const Component = (props) => {
return (
  <img>
  )
}
```

Компонент отрисовывает картинку. Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на картинку, она поворачивалась на 180?

Comment: Я надеюсь, что это поможет вам. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605289/2873538

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде так:

````
  const Component = (props) => {
    const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(0);
    return (
      <img onClick = {()=>setRotate(180)} style = {{transform:`rotate(${rotate})`}}></img>
      )
    }

```
````